# Custom Elements rendering once only

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom, custom-element

I want to be able to create reusable custom elements. With my current implementation, each of the custom elements renders only once. All the elements (all 4) are injected into the DOM, but only the first instance of each is rendered.

I have tried with both using ShadowDOM and not using it. Any ideas?

Screenshot from dev tools:
[image]

`index.html` (extract from `<body>`):

```html
  <body>
    <funky-header></funky-header>
    <funky-content></funky-content>

    <funky-header></funky-header>
    <funky-content></funky-content>

    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
  </body>
```

I have created a generic script to create custom elements from a .html file:

`index.js`:

```js
const elements = [
  { name: 'funky-header', shadowDom: false },
  { name: 'funky-content', shadowDom: false }
]

async function registerCustomElement(elementName, shadowDom) {
  console.log(`Registering ${elementName}`)
  await fetch(`./${elementName}.html`)
    .then(stream => stream.text())
    .then(async markup => {
      const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(markup, 'text/html');
      const template = doc.querySelector('template[alpine]')
      const templateContent = template.content
      const styles = doc.querySelector('style[scoped]')
      const styleContent = styles.textContent.toString()
      const elements = templateContent.querySelectorAll('[class]')

      class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
          super()
        }
        connectedCallback() {
          console.log(`inserting ${elementName}`)
          if (shadowDom) {
            const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' })
            shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content)
          } else {
            this.setAttribute(`data-x-${elementName}`, '')
            elements.forEach(element => {
              element.setAttribute(`data-x-${elementName}`, '')
            })

            const scopedStyles = styleContent.replaceAll(' {', '{').replaceAll('{', `[data-x-${elementName}] {`)
            const styleTag = document.createElement('style')
            styleTag.type = 'text/css'
            styleTag.append(document.createTextNode(scopedStyles))
            this.append(styleTag)
            this.append(templateContent)
          }
        }
      }
      customElements.define(elementName, CustomElement)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('ERROR:', err)
    })
}

elements.forEach(element => registerCustomElement(element.name, element.shadowDom))
```

An example template file:
`funky-header.html`:

```html
<template alpine>
  <h1 class="font-black text-blue-800">This is my header</h1>
  <p class="font-thin text-xs text-blue-600 my-text">This is a paragraph with a longer text, to simualte a descritpion.</p>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .my-text {
    color: purple;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: You shouldn't redefine the `CustomElement` class every time a custom element is being defined.

Comment: @Barmar - this is defined once per type of element. In my case I have two different custom elements, each with 2 instances in my index.html. So, the `CustomElement` class is cerated only twice, and not for every instance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as simple as replacing the `this.append(templateContent)` with `this.innerHTML = template.innerHTML`.